# Connect to local SQL Server Express database from inside minikube cluster

Tags: sql-server, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to access my SQL Server Express database hosted on my local machine from inside a minikube pod. I tried to follow the idea describe on [kubernetes official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service). While I am inspecting my container I found out that my application got crashed every time I am creating POD because the application is unable to connect to the local database.

This is my config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: sqlserver-svc
spec:
    ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 1443
          targetPort: 1433
===========================

apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
    name: sqlserver-svc
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.0.101
    ports:
      - port: 1433

======== Application container ==========
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod  # object type -> that will reside kubernetes cluster
metadata: 
    name: api-pod
    labels:
        component: web
spec:
    containers:
        - name: api
          image: nayan2/simptekapi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_HOST
              value: "sqlserver-svc:1443\\SQLEXPRESS"
            - name: DATABASE_PORT
              value: '1433'
            - name: DATABASE_USER
              value: sa
            - name: DATABASE_PW
              value: 1234
            - name: JWT_SECRET
              value: sec
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: production

================================

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: api-node-port
spec:
    type: NodePort
    ports:
        - port: 4200
        targetPort: 5000
        nodePort: 31515
    selector:
        component: web
```

It is obvious that I am doing something wrong. I am relatively new with docker/container and Kubernetes technology. Still learning. Can anybody help me with this??

Comment: Did you specifically configure SQL Server Express to listen on 0.0.0.0:1433? Because that's not the [default configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/default-sql-server-network-protocol-configuration).

Comment: @do I didnt. Do I need to do so?

Comment: It's really up to you. As per the link, though, the default configuration of SQL Server Express doesn't listen on TCP sockets at all.

Comment: But to connect from application you have to enable tcp. Even tcp is on, isn't it possible to connect from cluster?